# How to detect Touch ID is available and not configured

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

In my iOS app, I can detect whether touch ID is available or not. But if the device has touch ID sensor and user has not setup the touch ID, im not getting any error message for that. How can I detect when user's device has touch ID sensor but he has not configured his finger print?

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the framework is unable to authenticate, it throws an error. There are several reasons why a device isn't able to authenticate.

- `LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable` The device doesn't have a fingerprint
  sensor.
- `LAErrorPasscodeNotSet` There is no passcode set on the device,
  which means that Touch ID is disabled.
- `LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled`
  There is a passcode set but the device has not been configured with
  any fingerprints.

If an error is thrown with any of the above error codes, then you need to provide some other method for users to authenticate. At this point, you can't rely solely on Touch ID.

From [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949)